# Google Voice integration

Tags: google-voice

My wife hates that she can't call my cell phone without it ringing the house too.

Can I use use Google Voice integration but also keep my cell number from calling all my forwarding numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. Under the Advanced Options - Forwarding Options for the cell phone you'll see 2 options. I needed to change it off of "Ring my other phones before going to voicemail"

[image]